# Powershell Register Scheduled task with -user switch

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

Here is a powershell script I was attempting to use but running into an error related to the user switch. The odd thing is it works on my test computer but not production users and I can't find the cause:

## Create, run, then delete the uninstall scheduled task

```
$execute = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"
$execute2 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"

$time = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(5)
$triggerAt = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $time -Once
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $execute
$action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $execute
$currentusr = (Get-WmiObject -class win32_process -ComputerName 'localhost' | Where-Object name -Match explorer).getowner().user

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Open Chrome" -Trigger $triggerAt -Action $action -User $currentusr
Start-Sleep 6


Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Open Chromex86" -Trigger $triggerAt -Action $action2 -User $currentusr
Start-Sleep 6

Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Open Chromex86" -Confirm:$false
Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Open Chrome" -Confirm:$false
`
```

Can anyone let me know what I am missing, thanks in advance.

Creating a scheduled user under the context of the user logged in as the user running explorer.
If I remove the user switch the command works so it appears to be only that switch.

Error here:

```
Register-ScheduledTask : The parameter is incorrect. (15,8):UserId:
At line:1 char:1 + Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Open Chrome" -Trigger $triggerAt -A ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-Schedule dTask], CimException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: BUMP - is there a better way to script a current user? Still not sure how it's running with no error on a couple test machines while others fail, same ps version etc.

Comment: I think that using `-User` directly with `Register-ScheduledTask` (a) requires a (plain-text) `-Password` argument too, and (b) - more importantly - would run in a _service_ context, which contradicts your intent to launch a GUI application.

Comment: Instead, try `$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID $currentusr  -LogonType Interactive`, and pass `$principal` to the `-Principal` argument of `New-ScheduledTask`, and use the resulting object with `Register-ScheduledTask -InputObject`

Comment: Is there still a way to pull the user from the explorer.exe process? If I try to run this as is the tool I'm using runs in system context or admin context which won't launch the process under the intended user. Thanks so much for responding and the suggestion.

Comment: From a system context you can try the following to get the username (without domain prefix) from the active session (window station), assuming there is only one (I'm unclear on what happens on a _server_ with multiple simultaneous RDP sessions): `(-split ((qwinsta.exe) -cmatch ' Active ')[0])[1]`